# ¿Cómo centrar link con imagen en barra de navegación?

Tags: html5, css3

[image: ChromeTools img tag]

[image: ChromeTools a tag]

Como ven en los screenshots, estoy teniendo unos problemas para centrar un link con una imagen.

HTML:

```
    <header id="cabecera">
    <img id="logo" alt="Mayor Igual a Siete" src="../img/logo.svg">
    <h3 id="user">Username</h3>
    <a href="perfil.html" id="config"><img alt="Configuracion" src="../img/config.svg"></a>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#cabecera {
    background-color: #393E46;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#cabecera * {
    margin: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}

#user,
#config {
    float: right;
}

#logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 55px;
    float: left;
}

#config {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

#user {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Aplicale las propiedades #config a la imagen directamente. En el width y height usa los predeterminados de la imagen.

Comment: A que te refieres con "centrar el link" ??? ¿puedes explicarnos donde debería estar?

Answer (score 4):

El problema es el siguiente:

- En la cabecera defines un alto de línea (`line-height`) de 50 pixels:

  ```
  #cabecera {
      background-color: #393E46;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      height: 50px;
  }
  ```

  **El alto de línea es una propiedad que es heredada por los descendientes**. Eso quiere decir que si sus descendientes no definen esa propiedad, tomarán el valor del padre (fuentes: [artículo de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) y [wiki de W3](https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height)).
- Indicas que el enlace es un bloque de 20x20 pixels:

  ```
  #config {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
  }
  ```

  pero al heredar el alto de línea de 50 pixel, la imagen se va a ver por debajo del enlace.

---

**Solución**:

Define el alto de línea (`line-height`) para `#config`, para que tenga el mismo valor del alto de la caja (20px) y no herede el valor de `#cabecera`. Y si quieres que la imagen/el enlace quede centrada con el texto (ahora la imagen se vería más arriba), añade un margen arriba (`margin-top`) para centrar el enlace dentro de la cabecera:

```
#config {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  /** NUEVOS ESTILOS **/
  margin-top:15px;
  line-height:20px;
}
```

El resultado final se vería así (he puesto el enlace con fondo rojo para que se vea que acaba centrado y alineado con la imagen):

```css
#cabecera {
  background-color: #393E46;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#cabecera * {
  margin: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
}

#user,
#config {
  float: right;
}

#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 55px;
  float: left;
}

#config {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  /** NUEVOS ESTILOS **/
  margin-top:15px;
  line-height:20px;
  background:red;
}

#user {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<header id="cabecera">
  <img id="logo" alt="Mayor Igual a Siete" src="http://lorempixel.com/50/55/people">
  <h3 id="user">Username</h3>
  <a href="perfil.html" id="config"><img alt="Configuracion" src="http://lorempixel.com/12/12/nature"></a>
</header>
```

Puede que tengas que darle al botón de "Pantalla completa" para ver el enlace.